# Custom colors in vim syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

When writing a syntax highlighter for vim you can use the following:

```
highlight link foo      Identifier
```

However, can I use a custom color, say Grey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of linking to an existing highlight group, you can specify colors (and attributes like bold and italic). See `:help highlight-args` for details.

```
:highlight foo  ctermfg=Grey guifg=Grey
```